# Properly using 3rd party libraries, scripts in unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This should be a simple question for any experienced developer in unity/c#, but my lack of experience is forcing me to ask.

I recently purchased Infinite Runner Engine from More Mountains - a script that should have kickstarted my project but I'm struggling...

I'm trying to separate their code from my own so once there is an update I can easily swap it without making (too much) damage.

**Here's the question:**

Let's take for example their LevelManager script:

```
using MoreMountains.Tools;

namespace MoreMountains.InfiniteRunnerEngine
{
    public class LevelManager : Singleton<LevelManager>
    {
        // default methods
        protected virtual void PrepareStart() {}
        protected virtual IEnumerator PrepareStartCountdown() {}
        public virtual void LevelStart() {}
        .... and so on...
    }
}
```

To avoid update damage I thought of doing things this way

```
using MoreMountains.Tools;
using MoreMountains.InfiniteRunnerEngine;

namespace MyNamespace.Test
{
    public class TestLevelManager : LevelManager
    {
        // custom property
        public GameObject TestGameObject;

        // Overrides to existing methods
        protected override void PrepareStart() {}
        protected override IEnumerator PrepareStartCountdown() {}
        public override void LevelStart() {}
        .... and so on...
    }
}
```

I realized that I won`t be able to add any custom methods to the TestLevelManager class this way.

Does anyone have an advice on how to properly organize code?

Is the solution to simply use existing methods in their classes and override only those that already exist, and then to create additional classes for methods I need?
Sound too dirty that way.

I could end up with:

- LevelManager which contains their expected methods,
- TestLevelManager which overrides their LevelManager methods like in example above
- TestLevelManagerExtra that contains all extra methods I need for the game, like

This would be my 3rd example file for Extra Methods I would use
    using MoreMountains.Tools;
    using MoreMountains.InfiniteRunnerEngine;

```
namespace MyNamespace.Test
{

    public class TestLevelManagerExtra : Singleton<TestLevelManagerExtra>
    {
        // store relation to my overriding class
        public TestLevelManager testLevelManager;

        // when class is initiated it should find
        // my class and store it in testLevelManager variable
        public virtual void Start()
        {
            testLevelManager = gameObject.GetComponent<TestLevelManager>();
        }

        // custom method to be used outside of this class
        // it should let me access properties in TestLevelManager 
        public void AccessTestGameObject(bool state)
        {
            testLevelManager.SetActive(state);
        }

        public void CustomMethod1() {}
    }
}
```

Sorry for wrong terminology used in asking question, as I said, I'm not good at C#.

Comment: *I realized that I won't be able to add any custom methods to the TestLevelManager class this way.*, why? I'm not a unity user but you can add whatever methods you want to `TestLevelManager`?

Comment: Might have been doing something wrong then. When I add custom method like that, I can call it within itself, but externally it's not reachable...

Comment: You can't add any overrides, because they're not implemented in the base but you can add any method you want, just don't use the `override` keyword.

Comment: "but externally it's not reachable" can you show an example? Are you typing this "external" as `TestLevelManager` or `LevelManager`?

Comment: Is there a way to access that new methods from outside?
If I try to access this:
LevelManager.Instance.PrepareStart()
it works.

If I try to access this:
TestLevelManager.Instance.CustomMethod()
it says that CustomMethod is not defined in LevelManager

ouch, comments aren`t styled...

Comment: I have a class, let's call it GameManager from which I access LevelManager. I can access LevelManager.Instance.method() but I can`t access LevelManager.Instance.customMethod() or TestLevelManager.Instance.customMethod()

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170139/discussion-between-goran-usljebrka-and-liam).

Comment: It looks like the Singleton class (which looks like it inherits from monobehaviour) is not defined properly. It seems the singleton class does not properly support inheritance.

I had this problem myself when creating my own singleton class, but i managed to find a fix for it. Let me know if you still have the problem as that might be the solution.

Comment: @Immorality I'll find a workaround around my workarounds. :-) I'm hoping to see if there is a good way to do this, e.g. how people use 3rd party libraries. right now, I'll go with 2 classes per one base class, one to override it and 2nd to add new methods.
I'd likely look at whatever snippets/screenshots you got.